# Where can I find the following math paper?

Tags: paper-request

I'm a newbie in the field of mathematical research and I'm not able to find the following paper:

> " M. Radić, A definition of the determinant of a rectangular matrix,
> (Serbo-Croatian summary) Glasnik Mat. Ser. III 1(21) (1966), 17–22 "

Please could you provide me a link to this paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the paper at this [link](https://books.google.it/books?id=5z0GkLQ6LfgC&pg=PA17&redir_esc=y&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false). The table of contents is at the [journal site](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/).

Comment: Perhaps explain you you found that...?

Comment: Tools for this kind of search are both Google and Scholar Google. It is important to identify what is the journal that could have a website as in this case. It is a lucky event as copies of the articles are on Google and can be freely downloaded.

Comment: I know this, but I think to make your answer more useful than "giving a man a fish", and generalisable past this one example, having more information would be better.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 17):

In future, Google Scholar is your friend, and while MathSciNet is mostly behind a paywall, if you have some form of library or institutional access, then that is even better. Zentrallblatt (zbmath) is free and similar. I searched Google for the author and title, and that led me to https://eudml.org/doc/266996 (EuDML is another good resource), and on that page there is a listing of the references of that paper, including the one you want, with the link http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/advanced/?q=an:0168.02703, on this page there is a scan of a review and links to citing literature, which you probably should check out. Clicking on the journal title takes me to https://zbmath.org/serials/?q=se%3A1578. On that page there is a link to the journal webpage, http://web.math.hr/glasnik/. There I find the all volumes link, https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/PastVol.html, and so you can find your way to the article you are after...